# Grid showing a loader continouisly and a popup something went wrong

Tags: magento2, customer, grid, overrides

I created 2 sub menu under All customer and i created two grids the first for customers that belong to group1 and the second for customers that belong to group 2 but still don(t know how to filter the grid just creating grid now but i have this loader. This is my code Namspace/module/etc/di:`

    
    
        
            Magento\Customer\Model\Resource\Customer\Collection
            LocalGridFilterPool

```
<!-- Create our type LocalGridFilterPool -->
<virtualType name="LocalGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
            <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<!-- Type for client_local_listing_data_source -->
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="client_local_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<!-- Simulate our class Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection -->
<virtualType name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">customer_entity</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

`and this is my client_local_listing.xml:`
    
    
        
            
            client_local_listing.client_local_listing_data_source
            
            client_local_listing.client_local_listing_data_source
        
    
    
    
        
            CustomerGridDataProvider 
            client_local_listing_data_source 
            entity_id 
            id

```
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- Primary key column name -->
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<!-- Container Listing Top -->
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <!-- Button to manage views -->
    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                    <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">client_local_listing</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>
    <!-- Button to manage columns -->
    <container name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">client_local_listing.client_local_listing.client_local_columns</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </container>
</container>
<columns name="client_local_columns">

    <column name="name" sortOrder="30">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Name</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="email" sortOrder="40">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <editor>
                <editorType>text</editorType>
            </editor>
            <label translate="true">Email</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="group_id" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="50">
        <settings>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <editor>
                <editorType>select</editorType>
            </editor>
            <dataType>select</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Group</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="billing_telephone" sortOrder="60">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <editor>
                <editorType>text</editorType>
            </editor>
            <label translate="true">Phone</label>
        </settings>
    </column>


    <column name="website_id" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Websites" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="110">
        <settings>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <editor>
                <editorType>select</editorType>
            </editor>
            <dataType>select</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Web Site</label>
        </settings>
    </column>

    <column name="created_in" sortOrder="140">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Account Created in</label>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="billing_full" sortOrder="150">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Billing Address</label>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="shipping_full" sortOrder="160">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Shipping Address</label>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="dob" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="170">
        <settings>
            <timezone>false</timezone>
            <dateFormat>MMM d, y</dateFormat>
            <skipTimeZoneConversion>true</skipTimeZoneConversion>
            <filter>dateRange</filter>
            <dataType>date</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Date of Birth</label>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="taxvat" sortOrder="180">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <editor>
                <editorType>text</editorType>
            </editor>
            <label translate="true">Tax VAT Number</label>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="gender" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="190">
        <settings>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <editor>
                <editorType>select</editorType>
            </editor>
            <dataType>select</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Gender</label>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="billing_street" sortOrder="200">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Street Address</label>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="billing_city" sortOrder="210">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <editor>
                <editorType>text</editorType>
            </editor>
            <label translate="true">City</label>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>


    <column name="billing_company" sortOrder="240">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <editor>
                <editorType>text</editorType>
            </editor>
            <label translate="true">Company</label>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>


</columns>
```

`
but as result i have this :
[image]

please help me it's very necessary for me to fix that becuase i have a deadline for this project in my entreprise and i still a biginner in magento 2

Comment: Have you check consol or magento log files?

Comment: the console is empty a

Comment: is it possible to share extension so i can try in my default magento 2 local setup.

Comment: JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
/Selecta/interfBO_stf_COM/mui/index/render/key/ad0d08fbaaf63f457c9fede15533847a70a07765ed605b6dcdac144178f74536/?namespace=client_local_listing&sorting%5Bfield%5D=billing_telephone&sorting%5Bdirection%5D=asc&isAjax=true:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: how to share the extension please ??

Comment: Try to make only one column in grid. hope

Comment: share it on dropbox and share link in comments

Comment: ok i will try that

Comment: now the  the popup disappeared but the loader still there

Comment: here is the link to dropbox : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i9rXNFQ_6nXgdGc8cTOBGMZ9r7dxto3Q/view?ts=5bed7f2b

Comment: I will be very thankfull if you look to the code and help me resolve this